# Converting a function to spherical hermonic

Tags: harmonic-analysis, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

A function is given like : $ f(\mathbf{r}) = (x + y + z) \ \ \ f(|\mathbf{r}|)$

I need to covert this equation to spherical harmonic form to find out specific Eigen state.To do this, first i converted them into spherical coordinates :

$${\begin{aligned}x&=r\sin \theta \cos \varphi \\y&=r\sin \theta \sin \varphi \\z&=r\cos \theta \end{aligned}}$$

After putting these values into the main equation i get:

$$\psi (r, \theta, \phi) = r\Big( \sin \theta  \frac{ e^{i \phi} + e^{- i \phi}}{2} +   \sin \theta  \frac{ e^{i \phi} - e^{- i \phi}}{2} +   \cos  \theta \Big) \ \  f(r, \theta , \phi)$$

If I want to write this equation according to the [Spherical harmonic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics), what happen to the function  $f(r, \theta, \phi)$  ? I can write the function as $\psi$ without the function $f(r)$, which in the right side.

Could you please tell me how to write the function in the form of spherical harmonic perfectly?

Comment: In the first line, do you mean $f(\mathbf{r}) = (x + y + z)f(|\mathbf{r}|)$?

Comment: yes you are correct. I have done the editing

Comment: Using the same name $f$ in $f(r)$ and $f(|r|)$ is unfortunate here as the first one take vectors as arguments and the second take a real number. Sure you don't mean $f({\bf r}) = (x+y+z) g(r)$ for some given function $g(r)$?

Comment: also kinda important to note that the latter $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ will become $f(r)$ as prescribed earlier...

Comment: If you want to get the spherical harmonic components you could always just use the orthogonality condition to figure out what weight to put on which spherical harmonic.

Comment: Plan b for converting to spherical harmonics would be to read them off the table you linked since conversions of x,y, and z are given there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

\begin{eqnarray}
Y_1^{-1} &=& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta \\
Y_1^{1} &=& -\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}e^{i\phi}\sin\theta \\
Y_1^0 &=& \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}\cos\theta
\end{eqnarray}

You can write

\begin{eqnarray}
e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta &=& 2\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}Y_1^{-1} \\
e^{i\phi}\sin\theta &=& -2\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}Y_1^{1} \\
\cos\theta &=& 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y_1^{0}
\end{eqnarray}

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x + y + z}{r} &=& \frac{1}{2}\sin\theta(e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}) + \frac{1}{2i}\sin\theta(e^{i\phi} - e^{-i\phi}) + \cos\theta \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}(1 - i)e^{i\phi}\sin\theta + \frac{1}{2}(1 + i)e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta + \cos\theta \\
&=& -(1 - i)\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}Y_1^{1} + (1 + i)\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}Y_1^{-1}+ 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y_1^{0} \\
&=& -2e^{-i\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y_1^{1} + 2e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y_1^{-1}+ 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}Y_1^{0}\\
&=& 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}(e^{i\pi/4}Y_1^{-1} - e^{-i\pi/4}Y_1^{1} + Y_1^{0})
\end{eqnarray}

The function $f$ then becomes

$$
f(\mathbf{r}) = (x + y +z)g(r) = 2\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}(e^{i\pi/4}Y_1^{-1} - e^{-i\pi/4}Y_1^{1} + Y_1^{0})rg(r)
$$

Note that the factor $rg(r)$ is not represented in spherical harmonics because it does not depend on either $\theta$ or $\phi$.

Comment: @Winther Thanks!! I completely missed it